# Numpy stack in the first dimension?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two np.arrays with shape (3,8), how can I make it into (2,3,8)
I tried with np.concatenate but it gives me only

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "<**array_function** internals>", line 6, in
>   concatenate TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to
>   a scalar index

error.
My a1 array:

> array([[0.08, 0.3 , 0.51, 0.37, 0.02, 0.52, 0.05, 0.08],
>          [0.77, 0.01, 0.08, 0.67, 0.01, 0.02, 0.17, 0.77],
>          [0.3 , 0.  , 0.07, 0.17, 0.11, 0.04, 0.05, 0.34]], dtype=float32)

My a2 array:

> array([[0.08, 0.3 , 0.51, 0.37, 0.02, 0.52, 0.05, 0.08],
>          [0.77, 0.01, 0.08, 0.67, 0.01, 0.02, 0.17, 0.77],
>          [0.3 , 0.  , 0.07, 0.17, 0.11, 0.04, 0.05, 0.34]], dtype=float32)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stack 200 2-d numpy arrays of size (100\*100) in a 3-d numpy array (200 \* 100 \* 100)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54042094/stack-200-2-d-numpy-arrays-of-size-100100-in-a-3-d-numpy-array-200-100-1)

Comment: You said you want to stack them, did you try `np.stack`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing:

```
a1 = a1.reshape((1,3,8))
a2 = a2.reshape((1,3,8))
np.concatenate((a1,a2))
```

or

`array = np.concatenate((a1.reshape((1,3,8)),a2.reshape((1,3,8))))`

Based on the error message it also looks like you may have forgotten to include parentheses around your arrays in the `np.concatenate()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following simple way to stack your array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[0.08, 0.3 , 0.51, 0.37, 0.02, 0.52, 0.05, 0.08], [0.77, 0.01, 0.08, 0.67, 0.01, 0.02, 0.17, 0.77], [0.3 , 0. , 0.07, 0.17, 0.11, 0.04, 0.05, 0.34]])
>>> a.shape
(3, 8)
>>> b = np.array([[0.08, 0.3 , 0.51, 0.37, 0.02, 0.52, 0.05, 0.08], [0.77, 0.01, 0.08, 0.67, 0.01, 0.02, 0.17, 0.77], [0.3 , 0. , 0.07, 0.17, 0.11, 0.04, 0.05, 0.34]])
>>> b.shape
(3, 8)
>>> c = np.array([a, b])
>>> c.shape
(2, 3, 8)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

While `np.concatenate` requires existing dimensions, which are created in [@Tim Crammond's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61597719/2988730), `np.stack` will create the axes for you:

```
np.stack((a, b), axis=0)
```

This is roughly equivalent to [@Sophie Roseinsta's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61597764/2988730) of using `np.array` directly.